# Swift， How to obtain the current display controller in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

UIPageViewControllerDelegate

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    let viewer = pageViewController.childViewControllers[0] as! KKPhotoViewerController //So I got controller is a constant
    print(pageViewController.childViewControllers)
    print(previousViewControllers)
    photos.selectedIndex = viewer.photoIndex
    currentViewer = viewer
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow!! please refer this stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Like this I will get to the Controller is not currently displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if self.pageViewController?.viewControllers?.count > 0 {
   let currentController = self.pageViewController?.viewControllers![0]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I should take `pageViewController.viewControllers?[0]` Rather than `pageViewController.childViewControllers[0]`